# Como imprimir um arquivo .txt no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tento imprimir essa parte do meu trabalho em um arquivo .txt (código abaixo), mas não consigo, pois na hora de dar Run no arquivo essa parte inteira sai em branco:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vale ressaltar que mesmo saindo em branco, o arquivo é salvo mesmo assim, mas todos os campos que eram pra ser feitos saem em branco:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queiram o código completo para chegar algo: http://pastebin.com/x8k5HgsZ

```
import sys
sys.stdout=open("trab.txt","w")

print("DADOS DE " + str(nome1).upper())
dados1 = registro()
print("Matrícula : " + dados1[0] + "\nTelefone: " + dados1[1] + "\nEndereço: " + dados1[2] +
      "\n 1º Nota [ " + str(vet_nota1[0]) + " ]   2º Nota[ " + str(vet_nota1[1]) + " ]")

print("\n")
print("DADOS DE " + str(nome2).upper())
dados2 = registro()
print("Matrícula : " + dados2[0] + "\nTelefone: " + dados2[1] + "\nEndereço: " + dados2[2] +
      "\n  1º Nota [ " + str(vet_nota2[0]) + " ]   2º Nota[ " + str(vet_nota2[1]) + " ]")

sys.stdout.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta isto, é outra abordagem para escrita no ficheiro:

```
#Salvando em txt
text = ''
text += "DADOS DE " + str(nome1).upper()
dados1 = registro()
text += "\nMatrícula : " + dados1[0] + "\nTelefone: " + dados1[1] + "\nEndereço: " + dados1[2]+ "\n 1º Nota [ " + str(vet_nota1[0]) + " ]   2º Nota[ " + str(vet_nota1[1]) + " ]\n"

text += "\nDADOS DE " + str(nome2).upper()
dados2 = registro()
text += "\nMatrícula : " + dados2[0] + "\nTelefone: " + dados2[1] + "\nEndereço: " + dados2[2]+ "\n  1º Nota [ " + str(vet_nota2[0]) + " ]   2º Nota[ " + str(vet_nota2[1]) + " ]"
with open('trab.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
print(text)
```

Comment: Dá um erro de: in <module>
    f.write(text)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: @KennethAnderson isso é porque a indentação não está correta, `f.write(..)` deve estar ao nivel das linhas anteriores (como eu pus), dentro do `with`

Comment: Agora deu certo, mas aconteceu um problema: É como se as linhas estivessem todas juntas, sem quebra de linhas. O que você acha que eu posso fazer para que tenha quebra de linhas no resultado final?

Comment: @KennethAnderson as quebras estão lá tanto no ficheiro como no `print`. Copia o que pus